# GWT 2.5 - CellTable Row Onclick (single click) Event - Does not contains Row index

Tags: gwt

I am using GWT 2.5 CellTable , I want to write Onclick event (Single click) to get perform some operation , I couldnt get correct Row Index while clicking on CellTable Row, Only double click event returns the row correctly.

Here is my code,

```
cellTable.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler()
 {
@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) 
     {
       CellTable<List<String>> selectedcell = (CellTable<List<String>>)  event.getSource();
        System.out.println("  Current Selected Row : "+selectedcell.getKeyboardSelectedRow());
     }
  }, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to sink the click event

```
cellTable.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           CellTable<ContactInfo> selectedcell = (CellTable<ContactInfo>)  event.getSource();
            System.out.println("  Current Selected Row : "+selectedcell.getKeyboardSelectedRow());

    }
}, ClickEvent.getType());


cellTable.sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK);
```

Comment: Yes i have included that statement too, but i am getting only previously selected row index , not current single clicked row index.

Comment: @DhanamRathinam: did you find out? im also getting the previous selected row index..

Comment: Below code will return the Selected row ,dgrid.addCellPreviewHandler(new CellPreviewEvent.Handler<List<NamePair>>() {

   @Override
   public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<List<NamePair>> event) {
    
    if("click".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) { 
     System.out.println("Current Selected Row : "+dgrid.getKeyboardSelectedRow());
    }
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm wrong, but you may try with the `selection model` stuff :
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractHasData.html#getSelectionModel()

GetKeyboardSelected means selected by ... keyboard... :-)